# Multiple Host web app (Redirecting/Routing) in Django middleware / view

Tags: django, routes, load-balancing, scalability, distributed-system

I am on a team developing a real-time django-based online game. We are designing the scalability component and are coming up against logical issue for the gameplay.

Each node hosts a unique 'game' which consists of multiple users. We will deploy behind a simple load balancer (ELB), to divide requests across our [N] hosts.

Because of the node-dependence on the game, I would like to include a piece of middleware, which is able to lookup and forward a client session if a requested game already exists.

Figure 1: lookup / redirect desired functionality
[image: Figure1, lookup or redir]

0-3 can be implemented easily, but we have not been able to find an implementation of item 4.

Assuming we run this code on **node1**, and we find that **game6** is located on **node3**, we want to forward the client request to **node3** such that:

- **node3** responds directly to client and establishes session
- future requests do not need to pass through load balancer

I am hopeful that there is a solution that would allow us to do this, either by modifying the HTTP headers (Forwarded-for, etc) and resending, but perhaps there is another method which we have not thought of

Other thoughts are:

1. Use DNS name for each node (host.example.com) to redirect client request as appropriate. (requires setup and known number of hosts beforehand)
2. Use the initial **node1** as a proxy (make independent request to **node3** and return data to client) (Expensive, since when we scale the probability of being on the right host initially decreases)

Answer (score 0):

i think this manipulations are a part of load balancers and the boxes behind load balancers doesent have to  manipulate the same. load balancers also able to manipulates the same. i am not sure whether which load balancer you are using. but haproxy acts a load balancers and able to manipulates the same that to which box i need to send the request. and this also saves you forwards/redirects.

Comment: The problem is that a typical load balancer doesn't have the context-aware state that we need. Games are not always created/registered beforehand, and the number of hosts we are leveraging is flexible, such that there's no one good hashing algorithm to determine membership.

HAproxy is appealing, but ultimately ELB is a better option for us for many reasons